# Difference between execute current query and execute current script in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to complete multiple inserts in Oracle.

```
insert into  table_name (ID, code, date_t)
values (schema_name.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '232323232323'  , to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into  table_name (ID,  code, date_t)
values (schema_name.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '242424242424'  , to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I can't complete them when trying to use simple ***execute*** because it gives me an error: `ora-00933 sql command not properly ended`

But when I using ***execute as script*** it works fine.
The main problem is that I can't explain that to people how to complete that script in the console.

Maybe there are some other options to complete multiple inserts in Oracle?

Comment: Which client/IDE are you using?

Comment: What about a trigger which updates `ID` from the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```sql
insert into  table_name (ID, code, date_t)
WITH data (code, date_t) AS (
  SELECT '232323232323', DATE '2020-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '242424242424', DATE '2020-09-01' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, code, date_t FROM data;
```

---

You could also use `INSERT ALL`; however, you have to jump through some hoops to get it to work with a sequence so I would suggest not using this option:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  WHEN rn = 1 THEN
    INTO table_name (id, code, date_t)
    VALUES (SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '252525252525', DATE '2020-09-01')
  WHEN rn = 2 THEN
    INTO table_name (id, code, date_t)
    VALUES (SEQ$table_name.CURRVAL, '262626262626', DATE '2020-09-01')
SELECT LEVEL AS rn
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```